# Why do shift registers (LFSR) use the initial state "all 1"?

Tags: shift-register, telecommunications, pn-sequence, lfsr

[image]In all books about information coding theory, scientists describe shift registers of various configurations, but they always use the initial state "all 1" in any configuration and any bit depth.
In practice, open sources of satellite and mobile communications also mention this initial state.
But, in the end, the initial state "all 1" is only one of the possible ones and does not give any significant gain compared to other initial states, why do shift registers (LFSR) use the initial state "all 1"?

Comment: Post a few links to documents which show this.

Comment: Because a 0 input ... lead to all 0 in LFSR. To be sure it is not "stuck", one must implement an "all zeros" detector ... for setting the first FF to 1. Not sure ..., but with only a 1 input, the sequence should be the "longest".

Comment: I doubt if this is true of all textbooks. Surely somewhere there is one that presents an LFSR with XNOR feedback, and therefore initializes the state machine to all-0's.

Comment: In a PRBS LFSR, not all XORs are present (multiplication by a known polynomial). One must be aware that if there is a "stuck" state. If true, one must "set" a first state for one (or some) or all outputs.

Comment: @Antonio51 in this case, the initial state consists of all zeros, since the inverse exclusive disjunction is applied

Comment: Note also that these LFSR "were" used by a "digital signature analyzer" from HP in the old time ... https://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1977-05.pdf https://arcarc.xmission.com/Test%20Equipment/HP/HP%205004A.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The choice is arbitrary.

In a Fibonacci LFSR with XOR feedback, the state containing all zeros is illegal since it'll cause the LFSR to lock up. (The XOR combination of any number of zeros is still zero, which means that the all-zero state transitions to itself.)

So, since the all-zero state doesn't work as the initial state, the other obvious choice is all-ones. This is simpler than choosing an initialization pattern consisting of both ones and zeros since you only need one type of resettable D-flipflop (namely one that switches to the "1" state when it's reset). "All ones" is also much simpler to describe than an arbitrary bit pattern.

However, if you wanted to, you could very well initialize the LFSR with any other legal state. You'd just have to describe and implement it, which is slightly more complex than just setting every flipflop to 1. It won't make any difference at all to the algorithm's operation.

In other words: The initial state doesn't matter, so they chose one that's simple. Why describe a complicated initial state when you can just say "it's all ones"?

Comment: All arbitrary initial states (except all-0s) are only equivalent in a maximal length polynomial LFSR. The example polynomial shown by Daniel has four different sequences, depending on initial condition, so initial condition might very well lead to different results, in general. However, since the example is not a maximal length PRBS, it's therefore is not really useful as a CRC-generating LFSR.

Answer (score 0):

But, when using a LFSR to calculate the CRC for a serial bit stream (a message), one of the things that needs to specified (besides the generator polynomial) is whether the LFSR is initialized to all 1's or all 0's, both of which will produce a valid CRC for a non-trivial message.

Comment: While initializing the LFSR to zeroes is possible, it is the absolute worst choise, because then for any amount of leading zero bits in the message will not affect the LFSR value, so added or missing zeroes will end up in exact same CRC. A generic CRC routine should also define final invert/xor value and which way bits are calculated.

Comment: Agreed.  In fact, the last interface I defined the seed value was specified to be 0xFFFF.  I was merely pointing out what is possible.